# makeindex replaces vertical line with backslash

Tags: indexing

My index entry contains a vertical line in math mode. `makeindex` seems to replace it with a backslash, resulting in an error when I re-compile because it thinks the text following the backslash is a command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

$(r|p)$ centroid \index{$(r|p)$ centroid}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I run `latex` with no errors, then `makeindex` with no errors or warnings, then when I run `latex` again I get:

```
Writing index file mwe.idx
(./mwe.aux) (./mwe.ind [1{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/up
dmap/pdftex.map}]
./mwe.ind:3: Undefined control sequence.
l.3   \item $(r\, \p
                    )$ centroid{1}
```

`mwe.ind` contains:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item $(r\, \p)$ centroid{1}

\end{theindex}
```

`mwe.idx` contains:

```
\indexentry{$(r|p)$ centroid}{1}
```

Note: Same issue if I use `\index{rp centroid@$(r|p)$ centroid}`.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in `makeindex`, the vertical bar is the escape character that introduces a command that is intended to apply to the page number.  thus it has
the same effect as (and is interpreted as) a backslash.  for example,
if you wish the page number to appear in italic, end your index entry
input with `\textit`.

if you want a vertical bar to appear in your index, enter it as `\vert` (in math mode).  (there are some alternate possibilities, but i am not
now at a location where i can check.)

this is documented in the manual: `\texdoc makeindex`.

Comment: Also `"|` would do. On the other hand, I'd define a macro for producing “r|p”, possibly with some kerning around the vertical bar.

Comment: @egreg -- would `\mid` be appropriate here?  (that would work, of course.)

Comment: It depends on whether the bar is considered an operation or relation symbol, or neither. In my opinion *some* space is needed on either side anyway.